# Can my Wicket validation rules be documented to the user in a DRY fashion?

Tags: java, validation, wicket, dry

I have a bunch of forms which use Wicket's built-in validation to validate.

A tester has just noted that it would be nice if they could see the validation rules before typing the value in and getting the error.

I would like to do this, but if I just put the validation rules in the HTML, the same validation rules are now documented in two places (once in Java and once in English) so they are guaranteed to go out of sync if anything changes.

Is there some proper way to do this while still keeping the code DRY?

Answer (score 5):

You could add a behavior to all your form components (through an IComponentInitializationListener), which analyses all present validators and renders this information into the markup, e.g. via a tooltip.

Comment: That would be incredibly useful.

Comment: I could use this kind of module too. Good Idea to solve this with a listener.